# App crashes using the new Android 12 Splash Screen API

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I'm trying to use the new Android 12 Splash Screen API but my app keeps crashing when opening the first activity.

I have `MainActivity` as my launcher activity **without** any layout file associated to it. When the app launches I keep the splash screen active while I check the current authentication session.

```kotlin
// in MainActivity.kt

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition { !authSessionIsReady }
    Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(onFetchSuccess, onFetchError)
}

private val onFetchSuccess = fun(session: AuthSession) {
    authSessionIsReady = true
    when (session.isSignedIn) {
        true -> goToHomeActivity(Amplify.Auth.currentUser.username)
        false -> goToLoginOrSignupActivity()
    }
}

private val goToHomeActivity = fun(username: String) {
    Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME, username)
    }.also { startActivity(it) }
    finish()
}
```

this is my manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.myapp">

    <application
        android:name=".AmplifyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.Starting">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginOrSignupActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the theme file I'm using

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Splash screen theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

As soon as the authentication result comes back the app crashes w/ the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.LoginOrSignupActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Since the error seems to be `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` I tried substituting `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"` with `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"` in my theme file but that didn't change anything.

Comment: New splash screen API? What? Google used to strongly recommend against having a splash screen... and they were right.

Comment: I implemented this, here is the solution: https://medium.com/native-mobile-bits/first-ever-splash-screen-api-in-android-recommended-by-google-1627fb5b274a

Comment: You should call `installSplashScreen()` before `onCreate()` as a documentation said: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate#migrate_your_splash_screen_implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the theme in application tag to

```
@style/Theme.MyApp
```

And add theme in the activity tag(of your main activity) to

```
@style/Theme.MyApp.Starting
```

Let me know if this works for you.For example, one can check the Manifest file of [my app](https://github.com/Sujal1245/WALLisWALL-Wallpaper-App/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. Btw, I get a bit of a rough transition when going to the first activity, I think caused by the fact that I first set `authSessionIsReady = true`, clearing the splash screen, and then go to the first activity, so in between the two I just see a black screen. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I am not sure about that, sorry. Btw, if my solution answered your question, please mark it with the green tick :)

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solution didn't work for me. For me the culprit were the newest versions of some androidx libraries. I did quite some testing and here is what is working and what isn't for me. Keep in mind that the versions between the stable and current newest, may or may not cause this issue, but I'm not going to test all of them.

Here are the libraries/artifacts that caused issues for me.

[androidx.navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

```
androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version
```

(Current as time of writing) **Stable**: `2.4.2 -> works`.

(Current) *Latest*: `2.5.0-beta01 -> causes the issue`.

`2.5.0-alpha03` is the latest that didn't cause the issue for me.

[androidx.fragment](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)

```
androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$version
```

**Stable**: `1.4.1 -> works`.

*Latest*: `1.5.0-beta01 -> causes the issue`.

`1.5.0-alpha03` is the latest that didn't cause the issue for me.

Comment: did you find a way to update navigation version and get rid of the crash? I have the same problem

Comment: @Martin.M I used the stable versions mentioned above. Idk how things are now.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and in case is useful for someone: I fixed it setting (in the manifest file) the splashscreen theme just for the activity that will use de splash screen (not for the entire application), for this particular case it will be:

```
<application
        android:name=".AmplifyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.Starting">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginOrSignupActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
```